MUI Backdrop scrolling to top of page
I am using the Backdrop's MUI component in my react app that is embedded on a larger website (I use a react Portal to select the root div for react).
The problem is that above the app there is more html content, and users need to scroll down to use the app. When I show the Backdrop, the browser scrolls all the way up to the start of the page, hiding the app in the bottom.
It there is a way to display the Backdrop without firing the scroll-up behavior?
or, alternatively, is there a way to use the backdrop so it fills only my react app, not the whole webpage?

Since you mentioned that the Backdrop is shown above of your other elements, it could be that there is some CSS applied to the Backdrop that overrides the position: fixed; top:0; right:0; bottom: 0; left: 0 that comes with the MuiBackdrop-root class.
I suggest you look out for CSS like this anywhere in your HTML or CSS (e.g. using the Dev Tools > Computed tab in your browser):
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;

or sizing-related HTML attributes like width and height:
(e.g. <body width=1000 height=1000>...</body>)
that could potentially override MUI's default styling.
